# Sitecore API issue

Tags: sitecore

I am currently getting 404 error for “API/sitecore/{controller}/{action}” calls in delivery server (after Hardening) but the same was working fine on authoring environment in sitecore. Please help

Comment: Did you double-check that your control's class name should be like "YouControlNameController". Add suffix "Controller" at the end of the name.

Comment: Yes i have added it.It was working in the content management server but not on delivery server(I guess it was because of hardening).Still unable to figure out what was causing this issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issues was fixed by registering the routes in global asas file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like routing configuration is different for these server. There are 2 typical places, where this configuration is done:

1. Check and compare your configuration of initialize pipelines on both
   servers: I guess on CD is absent configuration that is respond for
   this route "API/sitecore/{controller}/{action}".
2. Compare your Global.asax files on both servers.

The other reason could be in some additional configurations on CD server, e.g.: URL rewrite, HTTP redirect.

Comment: I have included the following lines in sitecore.Itemwebapi.config file .<site name="website">
 <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
<patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
<patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">true</patch:attribute>
</site>. Do any other changes required to make the call done.

Answer (score 0):

@Vikram Devasenapathy Please register your controller route in route config.

Are you using forms with ajax postback?